# How can I get VS code terminal cursor particle effects when typing?

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperterminal, hyperterm

Can you tell me how to give below kind of effect to the VS code terminal cursor? It is really nice effect :)

[**VS code terminal cursor effect**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-XYM5VcqAQ&t=57s)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use a block cursor inside of VS Code, add the following to your VS Code preferences:

```
"editor.cursorStyle": "block"
```

The splash effect comes from the Hyper Terminal plugin hyperpower:

[**hyperpower (Git)**](https://github.com/zeit/hyperpower)

[**Introduction to Hyper Terminal (Video)**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8q0KITkJee0)

Comment: Can you please tell the other step too? There is no extension on VS code as `hyperpower`?

Comment: The `hyperpower` plugin comes from Hyper, the HTML5 based terminal. [Here's my Hyper config with an explaination](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8q0KITkJee0)

This is unrelated to VS code, the block cursor can be used from within VS code as stated above, but the splash is related to the terminal itself.

Comment: Oh.. Is that mean I need to use the downloaded terminal to see that effects? What does this do then `"editor.cursorStyle": "block"`? In other words what for that?

Comment: Yup. That effect is restricted to the terminal. The block cursor in VS code changes the cursor from the 'line' to the 'block' as seen with the terminal cursor, but without the splash effect.